# What am I doing wrong with this JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json, formatting

I have wrotten this script in JSON and I put it through JSON builder and it says on the schedule line it is expecting string.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
{
    "ParentGroup": {
        "group_id": "",
        "group_name": "Group A",
        "schedule": {
            [
                "start":"9",
                "end":"10"
            ],
            [
                "start":"12",
                "end":"13"
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, check it here:http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some great tools to verify json :) eg. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter

Depending on what you are trying to do, here is one solution for valid json:

```
{
  "ParentGroup":
  {
    "group_id": "",
    "group_name": "Group A",
    "schedule":
    [
        {
            "start":"9",
            "end":"10"
        },
        {
            "start":"12",
            "end":"13"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Missing a ```:``` after schedule

Answer (score 8):

The schedule part should be:

```
    "schedule": [
        {
            "start":"9",
            "end":"10"
        },
        {
            "start":"12",
            "end":"13"
        }
    ]
```

It is an array containing two objects, not an object containing two arrays :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your schedule property is an object and thus expects property identifiers next. I think, what u mean is something like this:

```
    "schedule": [
        {
            "start":"9",
            "end":"10"
        },
        {
            "start":"12",
            "end":"13"
        }
    ]
```

In general `[ ]` denotes an array and as such does not need property identifiers, whereas `{ }` denotes an object in which every property needs an id.

Answer (score 1):

You're filling an array with name:value pairs that should be in an object (braces notation).

Answer (score 1):

i believe it should be like

```
{
    "ParentGroup": {
        "group_id": "",
        "group_name": "Group A",
        "schedule": [
            {
                "start":"9",
                "end":"10"
            },
            {
                "start":"12",
                "end":"13"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

because schedule is array of objects not object of arrays